# Poner imagen de fondo en Laravel con css

Tags: html, css, laravel, background, fondo

Estoy intentando poner una imagen de fondo en el body y no hay manera de que aparezca... la etiqueta está bien porque pongo el fondo de un color y si me deja pero poner la foto no.
A ver si me podeis ayudar, gracias!

OS PASO EL HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title> @yield('titlePag')</title>

    {{-- BOOTSTRAP --}}
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

    {{-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset("/css/style.css") }}"> --}}
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
 
</head>
**<body class="imgHome">
    <div class="text-center">
            <a class="text-decoration-none" href="{{route('productos')}}"> <img src="{{asset('img/foto.jpg')}}" alt=""> </a>
    </div>
    <x-footer />
</body>**
</html>
```

EL CSS

```
.imgHome{
    /* background-color: pink; */
    background: url("/img/inicioFondo.jpg") ;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

}
```

La carpeta la tengo dentro de public y se llama img

Answer (score 0):

Si colocas `background` solo te estaría tomando el color nomás, prueba con

```
background-image: url("/img/inicioFondo.jpg")
```

y después chequea bien que la ruta de la imagen esté bien importada.

Y como recomendación, quitaría la clase al body ya que cuerpo siempre vas a tener uno solo en el html y nomás bastaría con llamarlo a través del selector de tipo:

```
body{
  background-image: ... ;
  etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde veo tu código se ve bien, solo revisa en el inspector de elementos del navegador que la ruta que le estas poniendo a la etiqueta del  background-image si este siendo detectada por el navegador